# Find the extremas of $f(x,y,z)=xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Find the extremas of $f(x,y,z)=xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2$.

---

After some calculation, $Df(x,y,z)=0$ for and only for $$
\\p_1=(0,0,0), p_2=(2,2,2),p_3=(-2,-2,2),p_4=(-2,2,-2),p_5=(2,-2,-2)\
\\ H(f)=\begin{vmatrix}
-2 &z  &y \\ 
z & -2 &x \\ 
y & x &-2 
\end{vmatrix} \
$$
So this test helps only for the maxima $p_1$. About the other critical points, I've tried to calculate $f(x,y,z)-f(x+\varepsilon ,y,z)$ but both for positive and negative $\varepsilon$ the sign remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the point $p_2$. Then your matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}-2&2&2\\2&-2&2\\2&2&-2\end{bmatrix},$$whose eigenvalues are $-4$ (twice) and $2$. So, $p_2$ is a saddle point of $f$. Apply the same approach to the other critical points.

Comment: If $H(f)$ at a point $p$ has 2 same eigenvalues then $p$ is a saddle point? @jos

Comment: No. It's bacause at least one eigenvalue is positice, at least one eigenvalue is negative and $0$ is not an eigenvalue.